# Объединить два javaScript

Tags: javascript

Помогите объединить Скрипты в единый (на `textarea`)?

```
<textarea rows="1" name="twit" onfocus="this.rows = 4" onblur="if (!this.value) this.rows = 1">
</textarea>
<textarea rows="1" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Please fill me'){this.value = '';}" onblur="if(this.value == ''){this.value='Please fill me';}">
Please fill me
</textarea>
```

Comment: @amf1k, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: 21-ый век на дворе, а некоторые до сих пор все смешивают в кашу: внутри html-тегов впихивают и js, и css, и маму с папой туда же поместить хотят.

Comment: @Deonis так чем это плохо? Js вообще нормуль, да и css в некоторых случаях оправдано

Comment: @danpetruk, вы слышали про MVC? Поясню принцип в двух словах: мухи отдельно, котлеты отдельно. Во избежание путаницы не стоит в представление (HTML-код страницы) встраивать контроллер (JS-код). Максимум можно вешать на события элементов вызовы функций-обработчиков. Лучше вешать обработчики из JS-кода (тем более с тем же jQuery это не представляет особого труда). Насчёт CSS: я придерживаюсь мнения, что если какому-либо элементу нужно прописывать отдельный стиль - это плохо продуманная система стилей страницы. Лучше пересмотреть CSS правила и дописать недостающие.

Comment: @fori1ton про MVC отлично слышал. Впервые слышу о том, что кто-то использует его на клиент сайде. Если тег не генерируется посредством js, то зачем ему события скриптом прописывать. Тем более лишние обращения к DOM.

Насчет стилей - не совсем понял о чём вы. Я про то, что если html страница генерится не сервере, и в одном случае что-то надо вывести под одним стилем, а в другом под другим, то проще при генерации атрибут style указать

Comment: @danpetruk, возможно, вешать обработчики вручную и перебор, но писать код обработчиков (а не вызовы функций) непосредственно в атрибутах HTML, как у ТС'а - это, полный финиш. MVC используют в том числе и на клиентсайде, особенно при написании AJAX-приложений. В них модель - данные, получаемые с сервера, представление - разметка страницы, контроллер - обработчики событий. Насчёт стилей - для описанной вами ситуации существуют классы стилей. Представьте, что будет, если понадобится выделять элементы другим цветом, с вашим подходом придётся искать все вхождения элемента.

Answer (score 1):

```
<textarea rows="1" name="twit" onfocus="this.rows = 4; if(this.value == 'Please fill me'){this.value = '';}" onblur="if (!this.value || this.value == '') {this.rows = 1; this.value='Please fill me';}">Please fill me</textarea>
```

Вынести обработку нельзя?